# Android HTTPUrlConnection - Not loading full code

Tags: java, android, html, http

I was programming an app, which should be able to just retrieve all the HTML code a website contains.
Unfortunately, the app does not retrieve all the code. Its biggest part is not displayed in my logcat correctly.

This is one of my several logcats (I am splitting up the string I get in order to not overload the logcat):

> 08-24 14:08:19.560 7086-7395/com.derrobinator.vertretungsplan D/EXCEPTIONAL: o_soederblom_gymnasium.png" width="550" height="80" border="0" id="logo����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������[...]

My **fragment's** code:

```
public class LandingFragment extends Fragment {

TextView testtextview;
String str = "NO_INIT";

public LandingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_landing, container, false);
    testtextview = (TextView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
    AsyncHttpTask asyncHttpTask = new AsyncHttpTask();
    asyncHttpTask.execute(null, null, null);
    testtextview.setText(str);
    return fragmentLayout;
}

public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 10000;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.soederblom.de/schule/vertretungsplan.html");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("EXCEPTIONAL", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            int maxLogSize = 1000;
            for(int i = 0; i <= contentAsString.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
                int start = i * maxLogSize;
                int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize;
                end = end > contentAsString.length() ? contentAsString.length() : end;
                Log.d("EXCEPTIONAL", contentAsString.substring(start, end));
            }
            is.close();
            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        Log.d("EXCEPTIONAL", "ASYNCTASK E");
    }

    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
}
```

I was using the example **HttpURLConnection** code from the official android site. Does anybody have an idea? I appreciate any help.